# Jenkins: Which is the permission configuration for "delete this build"?

Tags: jenkins

I want to disable the option "delete this build" for my users but I can't find where to do it.

[image: Jenkins options of a build]

How do I prevent the circled option above to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this Jenkins documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security), it's the `Delete` permission in the `Run` section:

> Run
>
> ```
> Permission     Description 
> ----------     -----------
> Delete         Delete specific builds from a build's history. 
> ...            ...
> ```